# not able to index documents using app search(7.6.1)

Tags: elasticsearch, app-search

I was able successfully install app search on linux(ubuntu) with nginx as reverse proxy to app search, my configs are:

Nginx:

```
upstream kombare-search {
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    keepalive 15;
}

server {
    server_name kombare-search.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://kombare-search;
      }
}
```

app-search.yml:

```
allow_es_settings_modification: true
elasticsearch.username: "{{ elasticsearch_username }}"
elasticsearch.password: "{{ elasticsearch_password }}"
elasticsearch.ssl.enabled: true
elasticsearch.ssl.verify: false
app_search.external_url: "{{ app_search_external_url }}"
app_search.auth.source: elasticsearch-native
```

When I am indexing  documents - tried indexing with python API, curl, and  paste json -  they are not getting created.
e.g. with "Paste json" option
 
result:

Log generated in response to "paste json":

```
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.021+00:00][8913][2310][action_controller][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0] Processing by LocoMoco::DocumentsController#create as JSON
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.023+00:00][8913][2310][action_controller][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0]   Parameters: {"documents"=>[{"id"=>"park_rocky-mountain", "title"=>"Rocky Mountain", "description"=>"Bisected north to south by the Continental Divide, this portion of the Rockies has ecosystems varying from over 150 riparian lakes to montane and subalpine forests to treeless alpine tundra. Wildlife including mule deer, bighorn sheep, black bears, and cougars inhabit its igneous mountains and glacial valleys. Longs Peak, a classic Colorado fourteener, and the scenic Bear Lake are popular destinations, as well as the historic Trail Ridge Road, which reaches an elevation of more than 12,000 feet (3,700 m).", "nps_link"=>"https://www.nps.gov/romo/index.htm", "states"=>["Colorado"], "visitors"=>4517585, "world_heritage_site"=>false, "location"=>"40.4,-105.58", "acres"=>265795.2, "square_km"=>1075.6, "date_established"=>"1915-01-26T06:00:00Z"}, {"id"=>"park_saguaro", "title"=>"Saguaro", "description"=>"Split into the separate Rincon Mountain and Tucson Mountain districts, this park is evidence that the dry Sonoran Desert is still home to a great variety of life spanning six biotic communities. Beyond the namesake giant saguaro cacti, there are barrel cacti, chollas, and prickly pears, as well as lesser long-nosed bats, spotted owls, and javelinas.", "nps_link"=>"https://www.nps.gov/sagu/index.htm", "states"=>["Arizona"], "visitors"=>820426, "world_heritage_site"=>false, "location"=>"32.25,-110.5", "acres"=>91715.72, "square_km"=>371.2, "date_established"=>"1994-10-14T05:00:00Z"}], "dry_run"=>true, "host"=>"kombare-search.com", "protocol"=>"http", "engine_slug"=>"sp"}
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.128+00:00][8913][2310][app-server][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0] Engine[5e674d49f1f1792522921019]: Adding a batch of 2 documents to the index asynchronously
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.137+00:00][8913][2310][app-server][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0] [ActiveJob] Enqueueing a job into the '.app-search-esqueues-me_queue_v1_index_adder' index. {"job_type"=>"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::EsqueuesMeAdapter::JobWrapper", "payload"=>{"args"=>[{"job_class"=>"Work::Engine::IndexAdder", "job_id"=>"cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20", "queue_name"=>"index_adder", "arguments"=>["5e674d49f1f1792522921019", ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"]], "locale"=>:en, "executions"=>1}]}, "status"=>"pending", "created_at"=>1583831253136, "perform_at"=>1583831253136, "attempts"=>0}
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.159+00:00][8913][2310][active_job][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0] [ActiveJob] [2020-03-10 09:07:33 UTC] enqueued Work::Engine::IndexAdder job (cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20) on `index_adder`
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.161+00:00][8913][2310][active_job][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0] [ActiveJob] Enqueued Work::Engine::IndexAdder (Job ID: cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20) to EsqueuesMe(index_adder) with arguments: "5e674d49f1f1792522921019", ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"]
[2020-03-10T09:07:33.165+00:00][8913][2310][action_controller][INFO]: [5c2b4ba7-aa47-4d58-9fef-5af44147fcf0] Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 1.1ms)
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.032+00:00][8913][2290][app-server][WARN]: Failed to claim job cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20, claim conflict occurred
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.032+00:00][8913][2286][app-server][WARN]: Failed to claim job cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20, claim conflict occurred
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.042+00:00][8913][2288][active_job][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Performing Work::Engine::IndexAdder from EsqueuesMe(index_adder) with arguments: "5e674d49f1f1792522921019", ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"]
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.043+00:00][8913][2288][app-server][INFO]: [ActiveJob] **[Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Bulk-indexing 2 documents...**
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.076+00:00][8913][2288][app-server][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Adding documents ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"] to index for engine 5e674d49f1f1792522921019
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.191+00:00][8913][2288][app-server][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Re-queueing Work::Engine::IndexAdder for engine 5e674d49f1f1792522921019 document **["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"] in 60 seconds. Reason: Transient HTTP error**
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.194+00:00][8913][2288][app-server][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Enqueueing a job into the '.app-search-esqueues-me_queue_v1_index_adder' index. {"job_type"=>"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::EsqueuesMeAdapter::JobWrapper", "payload"=>{"args"=>[{"job_class"=>"Work::Engine::IndexAdder", "job_id"=>"cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20", "queue_name"=>"index_adder", "arguments"=>["5e674d49f1f1792522921019", ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"]], "locale"=>:en, "executions"=>1}]}, "status"=>"pending", "created_at"=>1583831254193, "perform_at"=>1583831314192, "attempts"=>0}
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.200+00:00][8913][2288][app-server][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Ignoring duplicate job class=Work::Engine::IndexAdder, id=cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20, args=["5e674d49f1f1792522921019", ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"]]
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.200+00:00][8913][2288][active_job][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] [2020-03-10 09:07:34 UTC] enqueued Work::Engine::IndexAdder job (cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20) on `index_adder`
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.202+00:00][8913][2288][active_job][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Enqueued Work::Engine::IndexAdder (Job ID: cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20) to EsqueuesMe(index_adder) at 2020-03-10 09:08:34 UTC with arguments: "5e674d49f1f1792522921019", ["5e674fd9f1f179252292101f", "5e674fd9f1f1792522921020"]
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.203+00:00][8913][2288][active_job][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] [2020-03-10 09:07:34 UTC] completed Work::Engine::IndexAdder job (cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20) on `index_adder`
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.204+00:00][8913][2288][active_job][INFO]: [ActiveJob] [Work::Engine::IndexAdder] [cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20] Performed Work::Engine::IndexAdder from EsqueuesMe(index_adder) in 161.42ms
[2020-03-10T09:07:34.205+00:00][8913][2288][app-server][INFO]: Deleting: {:index=>".app-search-esqueues-me_queue_v1_index_adder", :type=>nil, :id=>"cb95b7d95a1c24fcaa243d5591cf7711c13c3c20", :if_primary_term=>1, :if_seq_no=>19}
[2020-03-10T09:07:35.735+00:00][8913][2294][app-server][INFO]: [6c2fa469-cd71-45b2-bd20-4c2e3ef709c9] Started POST "/as/engines/sp/documents.json?query=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-10 09:07:35 +0000
[2020-03-10T09:07:35.739+00:00][8913][2294][action_controller][INFO]: [6c2fa469-cd71-45b2-bd20-4c2e3ef709c9] Processing by LocoMoco::DocumentsController#index as JSON
[2020-03-10T09:07:35.739+00:00][8913][2294][action_controller][INFO]: [6c2fa469-cd71-45b2-bd20-4c2e3ef709c9]   Parameters: {"page"=>{"current"=>1}, "query"=>"", "host"=>"kombare-search.com", "protocol"=>"http", "engine_slug"=>"sp"}
[2020-03-10T09:07:35.853+00:00][8913][2294][action_controller][INFO]: [6c2fa469-cd71-45b2-bd20-4c2e3ef709c9] Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 0.5ms)
[2020-03-10T09:07:41.012+00:00][8913][2312][app-server][INFO]: [40bd5f48-d72e-4b47-abe2-c76aaa0d518e] Started POST "/as/engines/sp/documents.json?query=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-10 09:07:41 +0000
```